# Verificacion de un dato existente

Tags: php, html5

Hola tengo poco conocimiento en PHP, pero con ello he logrado hacer una pequeña aplicacion con imagenes en la cual se puede modificar, eliminar o insertar en una base de datos con PHP y PHPMyAdmin, pero tengo un ligero problema al querer modifiar cierto campos:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: campos de modificacion de la aplicacion]

Como se ve en la imagen me muestra que ya hay una imagen, y que puedo cambiarla, pero si quiero solo modificar un campo por ejemplo el nombre "Slide1", me obliga a cambiar la imagen seleccionando una nueva y eso se lo tengo puesto con un REQUIERE en mi codigo HTML, pero si le quito el REQUIRE del boton con tipo file, este me cambia el campo de nombre por el que le puse, pero la imagen desaparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Osea me lo inserta como nulo y me da el resultado de arriba, lo que necesito saber es que debo poner en mi codigo php para que cuando ya exista la imagen, que solo cambie los campos que modifique. Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php  

include("./process/conexion.php");

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
        $query = "UPDATE tabla_imagen SET nombre='$nombre', Imagen='$Imagen', descripcion='$descripcion' WHERE id = '$id'";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

if ($resultado) {
    header("Location: mostrar.php");
} else {
    echo "No se modifico :(";
}

?>
```

El codigo HTML:

```
<?php

session_start();
if ($_SESSION["logueado"] == TRUE) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Modificar Imagen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
                <?php  
                    include("./process/conexion.php");
                    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE id = '$id'";
                    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
                    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                ?>

<center><br><br><br>
    <form action="proceso_modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" REQUIRED name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>"/><br><br>
        <img height="150px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Imagen']); ?>"/><br><br>
        <input type="file"  name="Imagen"/><br>
        <p><b>Nota: </b>La imagen se encuentra en la categoria <b><?php echo $row['categoria']; ?></b></p><br>
        <textarea name="descripcion" rows="10" cols="40" placeholder=""><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></textarea><br>
        <a href="mostrar.php">Regresar</a><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    }else{
      header("Location: login.php");
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu archivo "proceso_modificar.php" debes verificar que el arreglo `$_FILES` efectivamente tenga algo dentro. Una posible solución es lo siguiente:

Extrae toda la información del arreglo `POST`

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
```

Despues, puedes verificar si el arreglo `$_FILES` efectivamente tiene algo dentro. Si no lo tiene, es porque no se ha incluido ninguna fotografia y por lo tanto, no se debe actualizar la base de datos en ese campo. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
if($_FILES!=null)
{
    $Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));
    $query = "UPDATE tabla_imagen SET nombre='$nombre', Imagen='$Imagen', descripcion='$descripcion' WHERE id = '$id'";
} 
else
{
    $query = "UPDATE tabla_imagen SET nombre='$nombre', descripcion='$descripcion' WHERE id = '$id'";
}
```

De esta forma puedes asegurarte que solo se actualizara la imagen cuando el usuario seleccione una nueva imagen. Tambien te recomiendo ver [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) para aprender un poco de como protegerte al hacer inserciones a la base de datos.

Comment: Lo verificare ahora mismo :)

Comment: Y como le haria con la parte para ejecutar las consultas ejemplo:


`$resultado = $conexion->query($query);`

Comment: La ultima parte del if donde le digo que cuando se ejecute la variable `$resultado` me redireccione a mi pagina principal, como quedar ? perdon la molestia

Comment: No hay pena Santiago. Si te he respondido la pregunta, no olvides aceptarla como respuesta. La parte para ejecutar las consultas queda igual y la ultima parte del if tambien queda igual. Eso es independiente, no te preocupes.

Comment: Si me sirvio, solo le cambie esta parte `if($_FILES!=null)`
Por esta y me funciono `if($_FILES['Imagen']['name']!='')` :)